# ASP.NET Dropdown list passing parameter to next page

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am just getting back in to development after a fair stretch of more 'support' related activities so I am a little rusty. I have a project that I need some help with.

I am building a web application that keeps track of Donor Clinical Data (no names or anything just generic IDs like PT001 for each patient). I have a page with a dropdownlist that I have bound to a query. The label is the 'patient name', the value is the ID (For Example, PT001 for the label, 1 for the value). I want to treat this like a 'jump menu' - when the user makes a selection, the post back forces a redirect to a page where it will list all of the clinical values for that patient for all visits.

I have sorted out how to code the second page so that it selects just the data for whatever ID I pass it but I am struggling with the redirect syntax for the first page.

Here is the DropDownList Code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="Names" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id"></asp:DropDownList>
```

I want it to 'jump' to a page named `SearchByName.aspx?ID=` and then add the selected ID number to the end of the URL.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Did you find my answer helpful or are you still having problems?

Comment: Sorry I haven't gotten back to you. I did solve this and your answer was helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_OnSelectedIndexChanged"` to your control.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_OnSelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="Names" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Then add the following method to your codebehind:

```
protected void DropDownList1_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(DropDownList1.SelectedValue))
        Response.Redirect("SearchByName.aspx?ID=" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
}
```